# IBM MobileFirst Platform v8.0 - Network Error while calling http adapter from Windows application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm able to connect mfp server http adapter from windows cordova app. I have make change in worklight.js `xhr.open(method, finalUrl, true);` to `xhr.open(method, finalUrl, false);` for synchronized http request. It's working fine and app able to hit adapter successfully and I don't think this will impact. But while hitting adapter from app suddenly `0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: NetworkError` this error raises in visual studio then app crashes. In order to fix this issue I have to clean MFP server and re-register adapter and app again then only app works fine..

I an stuck in this issue so please help to fix this issue. Is there any configuration is there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will it work fine if you don't make a change to worklight.js file ?

Comment: No, without changing worklight.js I have not receive any response from adapter..

Comment: Can you share reproducible sample with server side adapter ?

Comment: function callApi(request) {
  var input = {
  method : 'post',
  returnedContentType : 'json',
  path : '/sample/apis',
  body : {
   contentType : 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
   content : request.toString(),
  }
 };
 return MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}

Comment: If you send me both client and adapter sample zip, it will help me to look into the issue.

Comment: The issue about connection should be debugged and fixed. You should not be making changes to IBM MobileFirst SDK. This is not recommended and not supported

Answer (score 0):

Changing  `worklight.js` file will modify the way MobileFirst Client SDK will behave. Therefore it is not at all recommended.

If you require a new feature in MobileFirst Platform, You can submit a request for enhancement in MobileFirst [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/).